# Is there any limitation on the number of topic references in ditamap

Tags: aem, xml-documentation, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

The DITAMAP loads the topic references in the DITAMAP dashboard very slowly in AEM, sometimes it hangs when there are a lot of topic references.

I have tried segregated by creating smaller DITAMAP's and referencing those into the parent DITAMAP, but still, some of the content has a lot of articles where it fails to load the topic references and hangs frequently.

Is there any recommendation on how many topic references can a ditamap have? Also, is there any recommended limitation to generating a website with such huge content or creating pages at individual ditamap's is a better suggestion?

There are around 4k and some have around 20k topic references in the ditamap.

Though it is specific to XML documentation in AEM, tagging dita groups for suggestions.

Appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no imposed limitation in the DITA specification for the maximum number of topic references in a DITA Map. But as your project grows you may encounter limitations in the tools you are using, either on the editing or on the publishing side of things. And limitations may be different depending on the used tools, depending on the amount of allocated memory or speed of your computer.

The largest DITA project I encountered belongs to NHS UK and it's public:
https://github.com/NHSDigital/DataDictionaryPublication

It contains about 50k topics and 2k maps. I think loading the DITA Map from the local disk in Oxygen XML Editor took about less than one minute and the publishing using the DITA Open Toolkit worked. We used that project as a way to profile and make speed improvements in the publishing engine: https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/3568

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @radu-coravu, In the above example, it seems it is well divided into individual DITAMAP's and a total of 50k DITA files, and around 9.2k DITAMAP's. Even after segregating, we have almost more than 30k in one single DITAMAP where it is taking time to load. I hope it might be a system limitation too. We Will see if we can decrease that into sub-maps and also will check it back with the AEM team on that.